# Jsoup: Unable to select certain elements though I can see them in the page's html source

Tags: java, html, parsing, web, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape the ASME digital collection for some research. I'm stuck at a point.
Consider this link:
http://mechanicaldesign.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1897362

The above link takes you to one of the publications. The page has author information, including a superscript (1) which mentions if the author is a Corresponding author or not. I need to find out which author is the corresponding author. In the above example it is "Julie S. Linsey". 
I have tried the following:

```
doc.select("sup")
doc.select("div[id=scm6MainContent_lblAuthors] a.disclosureLink special")
doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("href", "#cor1") 
Elements elementsByClass2 = doc.getElementsByClass("disclosureLink special"); // and then iterating on them to check if I can retrieve <sup> element.
```

None of them seem to work.

Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that if you don't provide a user agent the html won't contain scm6MainContent_lblAuthors

Elements inside are separated by span so if we get 2 consecutive "a" tags it means that author has a superscript

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mechanicaldesign.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1897362")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").get();
        Elements all = doc.select("#scm6MainContent_lblAuthors");
        Elements els = all.first().children();

        for (int i = 0; i < els.size(); i++) {
            Element el = els.get(i);
            if ("a".equals(el.tagName())) {
                if (i + 1 < els.size() && "a".equals(els.get(i + 1).tagName())) {
                    System.out.println(el.text());
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a bunch! I'm a newbie with jsoup and have only fundamental knowledge of web programming. I was wondering why was the useragent string required to fetch these elements?

Comment: I think that web server provides a different html for bots. adding useragent will fake a browser. you can accept this answer if it was the correct solution.